# Different brand shifters

Tags: derailleur-rear

Recently my Shimano rear derailleur broke. I have Shimano Tourney front derailleur, and Shimano easy fire shifters.

Will there be any problem if I put SRAM X5 derailleur? The front is 3 and the rear is 7 speed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It won't work. The two systems have different cable pulls.

Buy a SRAM (or Friction) shifter if you want to use the SRAM derailleur or buy a Shimano derailleur.

Either option is about the same cost (though if one is cheaper, the Shimano derailleur will probably be the cheaper one). You just need a 7-9 speed Shimano derailleur with sufficient capacity and cog sizes -- the Altus M-310 8 speed derailleur looks to be about 16 USD at the moment, which is probably adequate.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify Batman's answer.

SRAM has the same pull ratio for front derailleurs as Shimano.

For the rear, SRAM has a different rear pull ratio (described by SRAM as 1:1 rather than 2:1) so each 'click' of an SRAM shifter will shift about two sprockets of a Shimano derailleur. Some SRAM shifters have a switch that allow you to convert to Shimano pull ratios -- and SRAM sells some shifters that are only-Shimano compatible.

However, since you're replacing the rear derailleur, I would stick with Shimano as SRAM doesn't sell any Shimano 2:1 pull compatible rear derailleurs.

Comment: Actually SRAM 7 speed (mountain) shifters pulls 4.5 mm of cable, while Shimano 7 speed shifters speed pulls 2.9 mm of cable so it won't be quite be two sprockets as you suggest ([ref](http://blog.artscyclery.com/science-behind-the-magic/science-behind-the-magic-drivetrain-compatibility/)).  SRAM (1:1) shifters also pull different amounts of cables by speed.

Comment: Yes, the exact amount isn't quite the 1:1 vs 2:1 that is commonly used in sram literature and bike shop lore. Thanks for clarifying. But I did just put a sram shifter on a shimano rd by mistake and it was roughly two sprockets per shift. I've hedged my answer.

Comment: If you wanted to go 3rd party with Shimano ratios, Microshift is probably the way to go.